# Unity Rigidbody angular speed

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, physics

I'm working on a phisics based game and I have a question

Is it possible to make almost real phisics inside Unity engine??

Because when I put a rolling sphere at top of a ramp and let it roll... it moves very slow... and when I do it in real life... obviously the ball rolls with certain speed depending on the angle of the ramp... less angle = less speed... more angle = more speed

I tried:

- Removing drag
- Removing angular drag
- Changing the values in interpolate and collision detection
- Changing the mass value

Any help will be apreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to check the scale of your objects, it is very easy to set up a scene at the wrong scale because there's no easy frame of reference!

Unity's units map to 1 meter, so if your objects are extremely large, they will appear to move more slowly because the physics engine is set up to respect this scale by default.

A marble should have a diameter of roughly 0.025 units, and a person should be around 1.7 units tall!

Comment: No matter the size of the ball, the result still the same... maybe with code?? But how?

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is the scale objects. I found this link that may can help you: http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-fix-common-physics-problems-in-your-game--cms-21418